# Creating a macro that will search workbook and perform an if then else

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I've been trying to work on a macro that I just can't get.

I want the macro to search all the sheets in the workbook while using an if then code.

I want the if then to search the range C8 for a value "no" and if true, I want it to return the name of the worksheet.

This is what I have right now, but its not working.

---

```
With wsAddPatient

For Each ws In Active.Workbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible And Range("C8") = "No" Then
            .Cells(8, 2).Value = ws.Name

       End If
```

Update using Dave's code:

```
Sub NeedVolunteer() 
    Set wsAddPatient = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add Patient")      
    With wsAddPatient 
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
            If ws.range("C8").Value = "No" Then
                .Cells(8, 2).Value = .Cells(8, 2).Value & ws.Name & ";" 
            End If 
        Next 
    End With 
End Sub
```

This works!

Final:

```
Sub NeedVolunteer()
    Set wsAddPatient = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add Patient")
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    iRow = 8
    With wsAddPatient
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Range("C8").Value = "No" Then
                .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = ws.Name
                iRow = iRow + 1
        End If
     Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With wsAddPatient
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible And ws.Range("C8") = "No" Then
            .Cells(8, 2).Value = ws.Name
       End If
    Next
End With
```

If you don't specify the `range("C8")` as belonging to the worksheet, then the `activesheet` will be used - since you don't appear to be changing the worksheet this means you're always checking the same place. This should sort the problem for you and put the name of any worksheet with "No" in C8 into `wsAddPatient.Cells(8,2)`

Bear in mind that if there are multiple sheets with this value, you will overwrite any previous result.  Consider changing

```
.Cells(8,2).Value = ws.Name
```

to

```
.Cells(8,2).Value = .Cells(8,2).Value & ws.Name & ";"
```

This will leave you with a trailing semi colon in the cell but a full list of the worksheet names that matched your criteria in the workbook.

Comment: hmm its not accepting the code wsaddpatient.cells(8,2)

Comment: Because you have it in the original question in a `With` statement, I'm presuming you have a statement somewhere reading `Set wsAddPatient = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("whateversheetyoumeant")` ?  If you do have this set, what error are you getting?

Comment: So this is all the code I have right now:

Sub NeedVolunteer()
Set wsAddPatient = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add Patient")
With wsAddPatient
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible And wsAddPatient.Cells(8, 2) = "No" Then
            .Cells(8, 2).Value = .Cells(8, 2).Value & ws.Name & ";"
       End If
    Next
End With

End Sub

It went through without error now, but it doesn't perform the tast

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the process itself using the `F8` key?  The code looks ok to me, but it'd help if you posted it as an edit to the main question rather than as a comment :)

Comment: I posted it in the main comment! Thanks for working through this

Comment: When you stepped through it, I presume that the `If` step didn't prove `True`?  If it had, then the `.Cells(8,2) ...` code would have fired.  Which means that either no sheet has a "No" value in C8 or the sheet isn't visible.

Comment: I got it to work! I changed line 5 to the above. So how would I get it to fill the rows down instead of being all in one row?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
Dim wsNumber as String
Dim i as Integer

   For i = 1 to 10 'change 10 to the Number of Sheets you want to check
      wsNumber = "Sheet" & i
      If Worksheets(wsNumber).Range("C8") = "no" then
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8") = wsNumber
      End If
   Next i
```

This returns the Name of the Worksheet "no" has been found in. To keep it simple I just returned it in cell B8 of Sheet1, if you want to return the name on the Sheet where "no" has been found use: `Worksheets(wsnumber).range("B8") = wsNumber` instead of `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8") = wsNumber`.

**ADDED**

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Range("C8") = "no" Then
        ws.Range("B8") = ws.Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: How are the Sheets in your Workbook called? It doesnt work if they are not called Sheet1, Sheet2...

Comment: they are labeled with names. For example, Smith. John

Comment: OK, that changes everything :P Look at the code i've added. It should help you

Comment: It didn't come back with an error, but it didn't give any result

Comment: Atm it shows the result in cell B8 on the Worksheet the "no" was found, if you want your result elsewhere, then just change `ws.Range("B8") = ws.name`   to something else. Example:  `MsgBox("Found on: " & ws.Name)`

Answer (score 0):

You're close, just missing some code. Give this a try:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible And Range("C8") = "No" Then
        ws.Cells(8, 2).Value = ws.Name
   End If
Next ws
```